# How to make <dl> layout horizontally?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm trying to develop a layout for my website in which elements of a definition list will be laid out horizontally, kind of like this:

```
term 1                term 2               term 3
definition 1          definition 2         definition 3
```

Anyone know a way to make a definition list look like this using valid CSS?  Or if I can't do it with a `<dl>`, what would be the recommended structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<dl>
    <dt>term 1</dt>
    <dd>definition 1</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>term 2</dt>
    <dd>definition 2</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>term 3</dt>
    <dd>definition 3</dd>
</dl>
```

And in CSS:

```
dl {
    float: left;
}

dl dd {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Apply other styling as necessary. A working example can be found here:

> http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/dl.php

Comment: Normally you'd like to have the related definitions in a single list.

Comment: The fact that `<dl>` has to be abused (by including multiple instances as a single list) to do this actually exposes a flaw in the rationale behind the structure of dictionary lists in the current spec. Multiple definitions (or multiple terms) can be implicitly grouped by document order, but they can't be explicitly, declaratively grouped, which makes logically acting on those groupings nontrivial.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution, it makes 3 lists instead of layouting 1 horizontally

Answer (score 6):

Zombie question resurrection but the accepted answer totally breaks the whole reason for using a `dl` in the first place. There's a better way.

From the [HTML specification for DLs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) (emphasis mine):

> In order to annotate groups with microdata attributes, or other global attributes that apply to whole groups, **or just for styling purposes**, each group in a dl element **can be wrapped in a div element**. This does not change the semantics of the dl element.

Of course, easily solved by flexbox.

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Below is just styling. Adjust as needed. */
dt {
 font-weight: bold;
}
dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  dl {
     flex-direction: column;
  }
  dl div {
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>term 1</dt>
    <dd>definition 1</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>term 2</dt>
    <dd>definition 2</dd>
    <dd>definition 2.1</dd>
    <dd>definition 2.2</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>term 3</dt>
    <dd>definition 3</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>term 4</dt>
    <dd>definition 4</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```