# How to make a dl list horizontal

Tags: css

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Something</dt>
    <dd><div>Div with an image</div></dd>
    <dt>Second</dt>
    <dd><div>Second Div</div></dd>
</dl>
```

And when you run it on the page, it looks vertical, and I want it to look horizontal. The code looks like this:

```
Something
Div with an image
Second
Second Div
```

But I want something like this:

```
Something                     Second
Div with an image             Second Div
```

I can't change the dl and dt elements order, as it's a part of code that I can't modify. But all of them are tagged with classes or ids, so I can modify CSS.

So, is there any way to make the list look horizontal with this structure?

Comment: Hey, sorry for not adding what I did (I completely forgot). I tried what is in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485001/how-to-make-dl-layout-horizontally and http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/format-dl/#.UMsSzIP8LVA, but it's not exactly what I need.  .... Negative vote -_- you could simply ask me, as I obviously forgot... -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

This solution will also work with dl.

HTML

```
<dl>
    <dt class="col-1">Something</dt>
    <dd class="col-1"><div>Div with an image</div></dd>
    <dt class="col-2 reset">Second</dt>
    <dd class="col-2"><div>Second Div</div></dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
dt, dd {line-height: 2em;}
.col-1 {width: 48%;}
.col-2 {margin-left: 50%;}
.reset {margin-top: -4em;}
```

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/YNxCa/

Or you can use some other method, eg. with absolute positioning

Answer (score 13):

Solution using `grid`.

```
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Should be the accepted solution.

Comment: as of 2021 css grid is supported in all major browsers (https://caniuse.com/css-grid). you can add vendor-prefixes in order to support even outdated IEs down to version 10

Answer (score 3):

Check out this short grid version:

```css
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<dl>
    <dt>Something</dt>
    <dd><div>Div with an image</div></dd>
    <dt>Second</dt>
    <dd><div>Second Div</div></dd>
</dl>
```

css it with float

```
dt{ float: left; }
dd{ float: right; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For others using Bootstrap there is a [horizontal-description](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description) class for this:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Something</dt>
    <dd><div>Div with an image</div></dd>
    <dt>Second</dt>
    <dd><div>Second Div</div></dd>
</dl>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rh2otd6e/

Comment: For Bootstrap 4+ use the grid (row/col) system. 'dl-hotizontal' is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using flexbox. The downside is that you have to specify the height of the container.

```
dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 5em;
}

dd, dt {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

It works by placing content in columns (`flex-direction`), and forcing a wrap (`flex-wrap`) after every second element as the height exceeds 100% (= 2 * `flex-basis`).

Answer (score -2):

I would use a table for this.

Or if it has to be definiton list try:

```
dt {
float:left;
}
dd {
float:left;
clear:right;
}
```